# php convert date with two digit year

Tags: php, date

i retrieve a date from xml file with a two digit year like 'dd/mm/yy'. how can i change it to 'yyyymmdd' format. thanks for your help

This is what i've tried, but i'm getting this date 01/01/1970:

```
    $date =  str_replace('/', '-', $date_reception);

    $timestamp = strptime($date);

    $this->date_reception = date("Ymd", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Your code works fine to me (just change `strptime` by `strtotime`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` function

http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
$input = '01/05/16';
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $input);
echo $dateTime->format('Ymd'); // will output 20160501

// or in one line
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $input)->format('Ymd');
```

Comment: Saved mi laif. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert your date to a timestamp using `strtotime()`

```
$date =  str_replace('/', '-', $date_reception);
$this->date_reception = date('Ymd', strtotime($date));
```